# flask wtforms multiple forms on the same html page

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I can't seem to get the right lines to use 2 forms I created on WTforms on the same html page:

I define these 2 forms

```
class Area(Form):
    title = TextField("Title", [validators.Required("Please enter an Area Title")])
    text = TextAreaField("Text (max 50 characters)",[validators.Required("Please enter a Push text"),validators.Length(max=50,message="Area text cannot be more than 50 characters")])

class Message(Form):
    Message_title = TextField("Title", [validators.Required("Please enter a Message Title")])
    Message_Date_and_Time = DateTimeField("Date and Time")
```

and I want to display them in my `Dashboard.html` page where I embedded the code to display them within 2 different form blocks.

then I try to create view function for my `dashboard.html` where I call/define the 2 forms

```
@app.route('/dashboard.html')
def dashboard():
form = Area()
M_form = Message()
return render_template('dashboard.html',form= Area(),M_form = Message())
```

but I get a

```
    M_form = Message()    
NameError: global name 'Message' is not defined
```

I guess it must be some kind of basic, structural error, maybe I can t define 2 forms in my view but then how can i code this without having to resort to 2 different html pages (one for each form)?

Comment: Is the `Message` class imported where you're defining your route?

Comment: check if you have imported the Message Class in your file

Comment: Thanks that was it, easy one i guess..I don t know why but i was thinking all the classes that were stored in my forms.py (where i keep my forms) was already importedfrom Forms import

Comment: (finishing my comment above) I was thinking all the classe were imported from ` from From import` but yes you need to import each class too. I really didm t focus on that part and kept thinking it was some subtlety in WTforms. anyway now it works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Do `from forms import Area, Message` at the top of your script.